# What can cause Capybara::Poltergeist::TimeoutError: in group testing that doesn't individually?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phantomjs, capybara, mechanize, poltergeist

A Rails app that uses remote testing to test a CakePHP app running on a Vagrant Ubuntu VM.
My OS is macOS High Sierra.

```
'rspec/rails'
'capybara/rails'
'capybara/mechanize'
'capybara/poltergeist'
'phantomjs'
```

If I run `rspec ./spec/features/my_tests_folder/`,
the first 2 tests in the folder always pass and the rest always end up with `Capybara::Poltergeist::TimeoutError:`.

If I run any of the tests in that folder individually, they ALL pass ALWAYS.

There are 7 test files total. They each have 1 feature with 1 scenario. All are `js: true`.

I have tried increasing `:timeout` in `Capybara.register_driver` and increasing `default_max_wait_time` in `Capybara.configure`. Neither changed the outcome.

I've also played around with `Capybara.reset!` after and before each test. It didn't seem to matter, either.

When I ran this with `config.order = :random`, sometimes 5 out of 7 had the erros, sometimes only 2 out of 7. But, there were always some errors and some passing. Also, every test was in the errors group at least once.

I'm running out of ideas. What could cause something like this?

UPDATE (to include Capybara and Poltergeist configs and example of a failing test):

Configs in rails_helper.rb:

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  options = {
    :timeout => 90, # default is 30
    :js_errors => false,
    :phantomjs => Phantomjs.path,
    # :debug => true
  }
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
end

Capybara.register_driver :mechanize do |app|
  driver = Capybara::Mechanize::Driver.new(app)
  driver.configure do |agent|
    agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
  end

  driver
end

Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.run_server = false
  config.app_host = "http://my_vm_domain.com"
  config.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
  config.default_driver = :mechanize
  config.default_max_wait_time = 10 # default is 2
end
```

Example of failing test (not failing, but getting `Capybara::Poltergeist::TimeoutError:`):

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'agente visualiza estoques de um passeio', js: true do

  scenario 'com sucesso' do

    agente_log_in

    visit '/roteiro/show/723'

    find(:partial_href, 'new_passeio/723').click

    select 'Passeio Teste', from: 'passeio_produto'
    fill_in 'passeio_data', with: '11/11/2017'

    within('button#estoque_controls_0') do

      within('div#estoque_0_hora') do
        expect(page).to have_content('07:30')
      end

      within('span#estoque_0_vagas') do
        expect(page).to have_content('3')
      end

    end

    within('button#estoque_controls_1') do

      within('div#estoque_1_hora') do
        expect(page).to have_content('10:00')
      end

      within('span#estoque_1_vagas') do
        expect(page).to have_content('5')
      end

    end

  end

end
```

Code from `agente_log_in.rb` in support folder:

```
def agente_log_in

  Capybara.app_host = "http://my_vm_domain.com"

  visit '/usuario/logout'
  visit '/'

  fill_in 'data[AdmUsuario][usuario]', with: 'agente'
  fill_in 'data[AdmUsuario][senha]', with: 'pa$$w0rd'

  click_on 'Entrar'

end
```

Code for that `:partial_href` find:

```
module Selectors

  Capybara.add_selector(:partial_href) do
    xpath {|href| XPath.descendant[XPath.attr(:href).contains(href)] }
  end

end
```

Everything is fine with the other tests that are in the app's other folders. They're also fine if I run the tests in this folder individually. The problem only seems to happen when I run THIS specific folder as a whole.

Comment: Show your Capybara and Poltergeist configs and example failing tests

Comment: I've just updated the question to include that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After including the extra information requested by Thomas Walpole, I continued searching and studying possibilities.

I eventually came across [poltergeist's issue #781 on GitHub](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/issues/781), which describes a situation very similar to mine, and eventually presents a [`wait_for_ajax` solution](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/issues/781#issuecomment-228188089).

Before implementing it in my project, I read more about waiting for Ajax and found [this post](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara) very helpful, too.

In the end, I chose jasonfb's code from GitHub because it seemed more thorough and informative.

It worked like a charm! My tests now pass consistently. I was even able to remove customization for `:timeout` and `default_max_wait_time`.

The CakePHP app in question is very js heavy and the specific part that this folder tests is particularly full of Ajax requests.

Comment: As I mentioned over on github, the difference in your setup from most people is you're testing an external app so Capybara can't monitor for open requests.  I am curious what you're doing for `reset` between each test scenario though?

Comment: True. I just hadn't run into the problem until I started creating the tests for this specific area of the app. The app as a whole does have a lot of js, but up until this part, `:timeout` and `default_max_wait_time` configs had been enough. As for `reset`, at this point, there isn't anything. If you have suggestions, I'm definitely open. I tried to play around with that a little bit to solve this issue, but couldn't get it to where it made a difference.